# So do I have to install matplotlib with every python project that I do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib in the cmd terminal per instructions, but every time I open a new project and try to use matplotlib, it gives me the error code "No module named 'matplotlib'"

The only way that I have been able to fix this is to go to the PyCharm terminal and run the command

```
 python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

this installs the libraries (again) and it works.

But for it to work, I have to run the command for every single new project that I begin. Is this really necessary, or am I doing something wrong?

Be gentle, I am very new.

Comment: are you using virtual env for every project ?

Comment: If you want one package-setup for most of your projects, you can just point PyCharm to the global interpreter or to one specific common sandbox (e.g. a `venv` virtual environment). Just don't underestimate the power of separated virtual environments/sandboxes for individual projects. Especially, when you cooperate with others, it is a big plus if you can have a well-defined package-setup (via `requirements.txt`) that guarantees that everything behaves the same for all contributors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when creating the new project in pychram the default option is to create new virtual env.

if you dont want to manually install matplotlib every time you can do few things
option 1) when creating a new project in pychram instead of creating a new virtual env set your main python installation as python interpreter

option 2) When creating a new project click the option that says `make avilable to all projects` and when creating new projects in the future you can use the virtual env you created for the first project

option 3) when creating a new project and new virtual env click the option that says inherit global packages which will copy over all the packages installed in you main python installation (do note if you should have already installed matplotlib in your main python installation for it to copy it over)

but in my opinion its always best to start fresh with a new virtual env when starting a new project and then install the necessary packages
you can also create a requirements.txt file in your project and copy that file over to your new project if all the requirements are same for the new projects. pycharm will check the requirements.txt and give you a prompt to install all packages in requirement.txt file

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Modules are specific to the interpreter.  Each Python version installation has a main interpreter and then additional interpreters for each venv or conda environment you create. Once you install a module to an environment, it is always available in that interpreter (unless uninstalled of course).

Go to PyCharm > Settings... > Project: {project name} > Project Interpreter.  Select the appropriate interpreter.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. What is the reason for not making a library like matplotlib, numpy, scipy, etc automatically available, rather than having to install the module to each new environment?

Comment: That is completely up to you.  You can install it in the main python interpreter.  However, many developers will use a venv or conda environment per project, and install libraries within.  The benefit is that you don't haver to worry about a library update breaking a project, because you control the library version separately for each project.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find another way to fix it, try:

```
try:
      import matplotlib
except:
      import os
      os.system("python -m pip install -U matplotlib")
```

as a last resort option. this will automatically install matplotlib when you run it.